# Django - linkedIn API - client error(410) - HTTPError at /complete/linkedin-oauth2/

Tags: django, access-token, linkedin-api, http-error

I need to get some information from LinkedIn profile of a user to fill existing fields of my application form. So I am using LinkedIn API(I have created app in linkedin and stand with client_Key, client_Secret,r_liteprofile and r_emailaddress permissions). Now it is prompting me to sign-in with linkedIn and asking for "Allow" permission(All OK till this prompt) but In the next page I'm getting below error instead of showing json file with user information.

"""
HTTPError at /complete/linkedin-oauth2/

410 Client Error: Gone for url: https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(first-name,id,last-name)?oauth2_access_token=AQVpVZCnhj2oLkzUvQytDU89kJUMm5yEIadV0BZMid3WVqPSVdOiJIePGIH7ZL7i3M5gppOlbUqpS68rDaaio56Y-nkC3Njpvf91v8WUPxQ8t-3uqJRzCC_MdrKUpntLalp24Eo2BMjpYIKeHGdxjFIlaMt9tszkIVHpPcZA2-dgbqOBrvt9-QE4P91bTXqBBkrtHEXg9F560OvltnQDgc0U1xwO-5yOT5LjlqAtvDJ_gMf3G8rZ9cdkayq4aP1CO-ljglGqlJb4uxorPRg7qPqqkNaAmQjXploM0KVQ6pK7nidP4zC2l7WW1aqg38GRDe8AM8jzaiIkg-SX3JfCJA28fT9H8A&format=json

"""

Below is my code, Did I miss anything....I'm newbie to Django Please help me to fix it??

I have tried to get exact access token format like{access token:XXXXX,expires in:XXX} with url https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=[my_client_ID]&client_secret=[my_client_secret] I got below response.

{"error":"access_denied","error_description":"This application is not allowed to create application tokens"}

How can I achieve it??

````
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
    'bootstrap4',
    'social_django',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
        },
    },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social.backends.linkedin.LinkedinOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_KEY = 'my_client_ID'
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_SECRET = 'my_client_secret'

SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_SCOPE =  ['r_liteprofile']
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_FIELD_SELECTORS = ['r_emailaddress']
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_EXTRA_DATA = [('id', 'id'),
                               ('firstName', 'first_name'),
                               ('lastName', 'last_name'),
                                ('emailAddress', 'email_address')]

SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/home/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_URL = '/'

```[the error I'm getting][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECS3N.png
````